# XSL use regex group result + other element outside regex path for one outcome element

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="groups" as="element(group)*">
<xsl:analyze-string regex="^^([0-9-]+)([A-Z ]*)[ ]*([\(](.*)[\)])*$" select="/fault/informations/restriction1">
<xsl:matching-substring>
  <group>
     <x><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></x>
     <y><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/></y>
  </group>   
</xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:variable>
```

it was allready in
[XSL Analyze-String -> Matching-Substring into multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700584/xsl-analyze-string-matching-substring-into-multiple-variables)

but my question is how to use it on example to concate 
eg regex-group(1)  with other element outside regex path "/fault/informations/restriction2"

so simple IMPUT XML:

```
<fault >
  <information>

    <reference1>22-00 X (AA - 03 StoLAT)</reference1>

    <opr>Sample sam (66-33) Sample</opr>

  </information>
</fault>
```

and OUTPUT I would like to have
in one element

```
<mytrouble>
  <trouble12>AA - 03 StoLAT , Sample sam Sample</trouble12>
</mytrouble>
```

so the rgex group 4 - text inside ( )  from `<reference1>` and the whole text from opr

ps
currently by transforming:

> Cannot match item type with required type Error location:
>     xsl:stylesheet   /  xsl:template     /  xsl:element  /  xsl:variable     /
>     @as
>
> Details XTTE0570  :   The required item type of variable  '   groups  '    is
>     '   element(Q{http://xml.event/1.0}group)   '   ,
>   the supplied item type is     '   text()  '

GREAT THANX for

> michael.hor257k

almost there - just the result indicates header

```
<trouble12 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">AA - 03 StoLATSample sam Sample</trouble12>
```

Comment: Please show us a small but complete and representative snippet of the XML input and then show us the result you want to create using XSLT 2.0 for that input, explaining the rules.

Comment: Are you complainining about the namespace decalration `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`?

Comment: yes :) 
but it's not complaining  - it was a great help from You really
but if there is a way to exclude the declaration I would be double grateful for guidance

Comment: It is caused by code that you have not shown us. I am guessing you have this declaration in your `xsl:stylesheet` opening tag, and you need to add `exclude-result-prefixes="fn"` in the same place.

Comment: @michael-hor257k, of course THANX again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is how to use it on example to concate eg regex-group(1)
>   with other element outside regex path
>   "/fault/informations/restriction2"

To refer to another node within the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction, capture it in a variable first - for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="opr" select="fault/information/opr" />  
<xsl:analyze-string regex="^^([0-9-]+)([A-Z ]*)[ ]*([\(](.*)[\)])*$" select="fault/information/reference1">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <trouble12>
            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$opr"/>
        </trouble12>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```